# Design mySQL schema to save ebay categories

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, ebay-api

In my app, I am making a call to ebay API and save their categories to my local table.

The API response is a list of categories.

1. Each category could have more than one parent.
2. Each parent category could have more than one child category.
3. There could be up to 6 sub categories

How should the table structure look like? I am using MySQL and Hibernate.

The tree approach of id, name, parent_id cannot work as id could have more than one parent_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use another table where you store only the parent-child relationships

```
category          children
-----------       ------------
id INT            category_id INT
name VARCHAR      child_id INT
...
```

**example**

as a tree:

```
                       cat1
                     /   |  \
                cat2 – cat3   cat4
                         | \
                       cat5  cat6
```

in words:

cat1 has children: cat2, cat3, cat4
cat2 has no children
cat3 has children: cat2, cat5, cat6
cat4 has no children
cat5 has no children
cat6 has no children

In your tables it would looke like this:

```
category          children
------------      ----------
1, "cat1"         1, 2
2, "cat2"         1, 3
3, "cat3"         1, 4
4, "cat4"         3, 5
5, "cat5"         3, 6
6, "cat6"         3, 2
```

So in your additional table `children` you don't have a unique `id` but you can have each `category_id` multiple times, each time relating it to another `child`

**[EDIT]**
I added 2 to be the child of 3 **and** 1 (not that obvious in the tree). The children ids and the parent ids can occur multiple times in the `children` table. They are not unique.

**[EDIT2]**

This is a SQL query to get *one* parent and all its children (first generation):

```
SELECT id, name 
  FROM category 
  WHERE id=1 
UNION 
 (
  SELECT children.child_id, category.name   
     FROM children 
  JOIN category 
     ON children.child_id=category.id 
  WHERE children.category_id=1
 )
```

Haven't tested it, but something like this should do the trick. 
It will return this list:

1 "cat1"
   2 "cat2"
   3 "cat3"
   4 "cat4"

which you can format like this:

```
 1 "cat1"      <-- parent   
 |          
 +– 2 "cat2"     <-- the children
 +– 3 "cat3"
 +– 4 "cat4"
```

Now you will have to play with `JOIN` and `UNION` a little bit or simply call this statement in a nested loop for every *parent* and every *child* generation.

MySQL is holding 2D- tables with rows and columns, so to have more dimensions (like more generations) you have to put the data together either with the `JOIN / UNION` statements or outside the DB in your program.

Comment: How does it support multiple parents?

Comment: @Dejel: you can have multiple parents the same way. For example add 3,2 to the children table. that way 2 is the child of 1 and 2 is the child of 3

Comment: So actually children table is: category_id, child_id

Comment: oops, you are right :) sorry, yes it's actually category_id, child_id – I changed it

Comment: The question is now, in case that I have a parent category, how do I retrieve all the kids like a tree?

Comment: `SELECT id, name FROM category WHERE id=1 UNION (SELECT children.child_id, category.name FROM children JOIN category on children.child_id=category.id WHERE children.category_id=1)`   this is just a guess. If I am not wrong, the first `SELECT` gets you one parent category (id and name) and the `UNION` will merge it with a list of children (each of the children are `JOINED` with the category table to get the name of the category. You will have to adjust the query, though to retrieve the columns you want to have

Comment: so do you mean that I will have to do multiple join to get to a lower level?

Comment: The above will return the first level I could have up to 6!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look attached image for relations, You needs to extend according to your need. Hope it will help you to design your schema.
[image]

Comment: why do the sub_category and category tables are different

Comment: @Dejel: To keep Profile of sub cat items... it may vary with category

Comment: and what is the advantage of separating category to sub category and parent to child category? how would the retrieve SQL look like?

Comment: If there is any profile change then we could separate CAT and SUB_CAT otherwise no. parent and child will store the IDENTIFIER only to get parent and child. Data retrieving statement will be vary depending on your CAT & SUB_CAT by reference